# Good books on OCaml

Tags: ocaml

What are the good books on OCaml, which considered as a must read for OCaml developers on all levels?

I came across "Real World OCaml" by Yaron Minsky and Co. (https://realworldocaml.org/). It is quite a good introduction into the language, although biased towards Core library and its features. And so far I could find nothing more descriptive.

Answer (score 3):

Start at this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ocaml/info). I would suggest to read Jason Hickey's book... and all others in order. There is also a new book [OCaml from the very begining](http://ocaml-book.com/), although I haven't read it myself (only few chapters), I would recommend it.